# Unable to change network location while Firefox is open

Tags: macos, firefox

Under the Location option in the top-left Apple menu I have set up a few different options that let me quickly swap between different web proxy configurations when I connect to different networks. Normally I can just choose one and the new settings are applied immediately.

It has started showing this message if I try to choose a different location while Firefox is open.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

The location doesn’t change and Firefox doesn’t actually close. I have to press Ignore, close Firefox, change location and re-open Firefox.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: This is more than likely a Firefox issue, not quite a mac issue. Have you tried repeating the results with another browser other than firefox such as safari or google-chrome?

Comment: Yeah, no problem with Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Then it is a Firefox issue, which sadly won't get an answer here probably unless a mozilla firefox engineer shows up. :) ha

Comment: Ha, well you never know. Maybe firefox.stackexchange.com will show up first.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. I submitted a bug on bugzilla, the code is 1424709, let's hope they fix it.

Bugzilla link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424709

Comment: Nice one! Looking forward to a response.